# MissingManifestResourceException in VSIX Project

Tags: c#, vsix, vsixmanifest

recently out of nowhere, I get this Exception when trying to start the Experimental Instance (from within Visual Studio).

System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "VSPackage.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.'

When I build my project it gets deployed and works fine when I start the Experimental Instance App.

Does anybody know how to fix this, I couldn't find anything useful so far.
If you need anymore details please tell me. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Alright guys, repairing VisualStudio actually solved the issue.